# Laravel web application

Tags: laravel-4

I am new to laravel and going on to develop a web app. It has too sections, one admin side and one user side. How do I set the controllers. In admin side the links should be **mywebsite/admin** and in user side the links should be **mywebsite/**

I am using REST controllers.

```
Route::controller('admin','AdminController');
Route::controller('admin/place','PlaceController');
Route::controller('admin/acadamic','PlaceController');
```

Someone please advice me how it can be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing its much better to build your RESTful controllers around resources like this

`Route::resource('users','UsersController');`

For more info take a look [here](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)

Now in order to define your routes for the admin part you can do

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
  //this resolves to admin/users

  Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, all worked well. I used `Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
 Route::resource('','AdminController');
 Route::controller('place','PlaceController');
});`

Comment: What's the purpose of Route::resource('','AdminController')?

Comment: And by the way, if you found the answer useful, you can accept it :)

Comment: `Route::resource('','AdminController')` is used such that I can call functions in AdminController using **mywebsite/admin**.  Sorry I am new in asking questions, so I was not aware of accepting the answer. Once again thanks for your help.